# Not getting the desired results in a computed column when 1 or more of the columns used have NULLS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Did quite a bit of searching and found many examples of how to configure a computed column but could find nothing on this.

I have 2 columns - LastName and FirstName.  In some instances one or the other of these columns is `NULL`.

My computed column syntax is

```
((CONVERT([varchar](max),[LastName],(0))+',  ')+CONVERT([varchar](max),[FirstName],(0))
```

Which works great if both columns have data.
However, when one or the other is `NULL` the computed column is populated with `NULL`.

Comment: do you want to return the Row if one or the other is null?

Comment: Yes, if LastName is NULL I want to see ", FirstName" and vice versa.  If both are NULL I want to see ",".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating strings with `null` will result in `null`, see the remarks section [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177561.aspx) for more detail

You should handle the nulls as appropriate

```
CREATE TABLE People 
(
  Firstname VARCHAR(50), 
  Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  Fullname AS CAST(CASE WHEN Firstname IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN Lastname + ', ' + Firstname 
                        ELSE Lastname END AS VARCHAR(105))
)
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/188f3/1)

Arguably though, can it be a full name without both a first and last name, perhaps here `null` makes sense

Edit: if either `Firstname` or `Lastname` can be null then you'd want to do something like this instead

```
CASE WHEN Firstname IS NULL OR Lastname IS NULL THEN COALESCE(Firstname, Lastname)
     ELSE Lastname + ', ' + Firstname END
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4838b/1)

Comment: Really close, I wouldn't have figured it without your help. Slight mod though as the Lastname has little data so I just turned it around and this works as I expected. --  CAST(CASE WHEN Lastname IS NULL THEN FirstName ELSE Lastname + ', ' + Firstname END AS VARCHAR(105)) --